# How to solve (AccessDeniedException) when calling the Scan operation: User: arn:aws:sts... is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:Scan on resource.."?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-iam

I am trying to deploy an Instagram-like application to AWS using Elastic Beanstalk and Flask. After using **eb deploy** command, I am able to access the application main page, which does not requires access to DynamoDB tables. When I try to login, the application should access a DynamoDB table to retrieve data, such as number of likes in pictures, however it shows an

> 500 Internal Server Error

And my **eb logs** returns this error.

> ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the >Scan operation: User: arn:aws:sts::013051511429:assumed-role/aws->elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role/i-049593eb550052c8f is not authorized to >perform: dynamodb:Scan on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east->1:013051511429:table/cloudgram

I think this is happening because of an **IAM** misconfiguration, it says that the user corresponding to my EC2 Instance (i-04959..) is not authorized to perfom a Scan on my DynamoDB table.

I have tried following this:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-api.html

These are the policies I have attached to my aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role:

- AmazonRDSFullAccess
- AmazonS3FullAccess
- AWSLambdaDynamoDBExecutionRole
- AWSElasticBeanstalkWebTier
- AWSElasticBeanstalkMulticontainerDocker
- AWSElasticBeanstalkWorkerTier

I'm using:
 Python 2.7
 Flask 1.0.2

Comment: You haven't supplied an appropriate DynamoDB role for access to tables. AWSLambdaDynamoDBExecutionRole is for DynamoDB streams.

Comment: Which one should I use then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The policy you have supplied, `AWSLambdaDynamoDBExecutionRole`, is for DynamoDB streams. It doesn't allow access to tables.

One way to solve this is to add the `AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess` policy though a better way would be to create an IAM Policy that permits only those actions required and only those resources (the DynamoDB tables) that you need. Here is an [example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_dynamodb_specific-table.html) of doing that.

Comment: I added the FullAccess policy and in fact it worked! I will later try to follow this example and improve this! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with an extended cause. For people having the same, I want to mention [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69681482/aws-lambda-accessdeniedexception-when-calling-the-scan-operation-user-is-not/69683218#69683218).

It was because of permission boundaries.