# AWS Lambda - (AccessDeniedException) when calling the Scan operation User is not authorized to perform: dynamodb: Scan

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I try to access dynamodb via boto3 (Python) in AWS. Got this working on my local machine. As I understand in AWS running, it just uses IAM roles to get access. But it does not work.

```
  Lambda execution failed with status 200 due to customer function error: An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the Scan operation: 

  User: arn:aws:sts::021517822274:assumed-role/CodeStar-tt-api-subjects-Execution/

  awscodestar-tt-api-subjects-lambda-HelloWorld is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:

  Scan on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:021517822274:table/tt-subjects.
```

Quite the same question was send here:

[How to solve (AccessDeniedException) when calling the Scan operation: User: arn:aws:sts... is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:Scan on resource.."?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55497368/how-to-solve-accessdeniedexception-when-calling-the-scan-operation-user-arn)

And I applied the suggested **AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess** policy. Tried also those:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_dynamodb_specific-table.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_lambda-access-dynamodb.html

My own added policy (in addition) is:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "ListAndDescribe",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "dynamodb:List*",
                "dynamodb:DescribeReservedCapacity*",
                "dynamodb:DescribeLimits",
                "dynamodb:DescribeTimeToLive"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "SpecificTable",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "dynamodb:BatchGet*",
                "dynamodb:DescribeStream",
                "dynamodb:DescribeTable",
                "dynamodb:Get*",
                "dynamodb:Query",
                "dynamodb:Scan"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:dynamodb:*:*:table/tt-subjects"
        }
    ]
}
```

But I still got the same error.

Does it take a long time to apply the policies or what may still cause that?

Comment: From the looks of it, it seems that the role you have attached to the lambda does not have the required permission. Considering the error , it would be good if you also posted the policy for the role attached to the lambda

Comment: As said I also added this policy: AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess and my own one. I try to add it above.

Comment: Understood, but that’s a template policy… it refers to sample tables, which u need to replace with ur table names.Need to look at the actual policy used.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that the policy above is for the role awscodestar-tt-api-subjects-lambda-HelloWorld

Comment: Somehow yes. I used codestar and it create the role CodeStar-tt-api-subjects-Execution. So I added my role first and later the AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess. Is there something more to do to enable a policy change?

Comment: Oh there is something more: I see codestar added a "permission boundary". To be honest, I am not aware how this works. I removed it for a test and get a different error now "Execution failed due to configuration error: Malformed Lambda proxy response". OK but for now I looks like the boundary did this. But I dont understand it, as there is no dynamodb something mentioned inside.

Comment: Boundaries describe the limits to which you can go - and if what you are trying to access is outide or not defined as part of that boundary, you cant go there - so the if the Lambda Execution Role had a bondary that did not include the dynamo, it wouldnt be able to access it.

As for your malformed, response - proxy lambda has to return a json like object with { statusCode:200, body:payload}

Answer (score 2):

Now I found the answer. As I created my lambda with codestar, it also created a [permission boundary](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/permissions-boundary.html).

How to solve this issue:

- remove the boundary (not recommended)
- extend the boundary, like this:

**Edit the boundary of your lambda:**

1. Open console for Lambda
2. Go to tab *configuration*
3. In *Execution Role*, open the link to your role
4. Now you are in IAM role editor. Scroll down to *Permission boundary*
5. Copy that name (there is no link)
6. Go in IAM menu to Policies
7. Search for the copied name
8. Edit (extend) the policy.

In my case regarding dynamodb, I scrolled down to sid 6 (might differ for you). It is an Allow block with many simple entries and a * as resource.

So I extended this block with dynamodb entries. Now it looks like this:

```
...
{
            "Sid": "6",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "apigateway:GET",
                "cloudtrail:CreateTrail",
                "cloudtrail:StartLogging",
                "ec2:Describe*",
                "lambda:ListFunctions",
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:DescribeLogGroups",
                "logs:PutLogEvents",
                "sns:Get*",
                "sns:List*",
                "sns:Publish",
                "sns:Subscribe",
                "xray:Put*",

                "dynamodb:BatchGet*",
                "dynamodb:DescribeStream",
                "dynamodb:DescribeTable",
                "dynamodb:Get*",
                "dynamodb:Query",
                "dynamodb:Scan",
                "dynamodb:BatchWrite*",
                "dynamodb:CreateTable",
                "dynamodb:Delete*",
                "dynamodb:Update*",
                "dynamodb:PutItem",

                "dynamodb:List*",
                "dynamodb:DescribeReservedCapacity*",
                "dynamodb:DescribeLimits",
                "dynamodb:DescribeTimeToLive"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        },
...
```

Many thanks to the contributors helped me!